# I need to assign a variable to itself when iterating for the closure context to keep the correct value

Tags: go

Without i := i, I get an incorrect result (3, 3, 5, 9, 7, 15). With it, I get (0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 10), which is correct. Removing the assignment is similar to getting the value of i at the end of the loop. Why?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Handler interface {
    Handle(v int)
}

type Elem struct {
    Handler Handler
}

var elems []*Elem

type handlerFunc func(v int)

func (h handlerFunc) Handle(v int) { h(v) }

func main() {
    newElem := func(fn handlerFunc) {
        elem := &Elem{Handler: handlerFunc(fn)}
        elems = append(elems, elem)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        i := i // *** Why? ***
        newElem(func(v int) { fmt.Printf("%d, ", i+v) })
        newElem(func(v int) { fmt.Printf("%d, ", i*v) })
    }

    for n, e := range elems {
        if e.Handler != nil {
            e.Handler.Handle(n)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to visualize what is going on is to change the output of your functions to:

```
newElem(func(v int) { fmt.Printf("plus %d - %d+%d\n", i+v, i, v) })
newElem(func(v int) { fmt.Printf("times %d - %d*%d\n", i*v, i , v) })
```

With this change the output becomes:

```
plus 3 - 3+0
times 3 - 3*1
plus 5 - 3+2
times 9 - 3*3
plus 7 - 3+4
times 15 - 3*5
```

So, as you can see, `i` is 3 in all cases.  This is because you are creating closures around the `i` variable, so the functions will use the current value of `i` when they run, which is 3 by the time the functions actually use `i`.

You can again see this if you change your code like the following:

http://play.golang.org/p/FRhr0n2oi7

The reason the assignment `i := i` inside your loop fixes the problem is because you are creating a new variable `i` inside the scope of your loop which is still closed over by the functions, but doesn't ever change.  Each new iteration of the loop creates a new `i` so no previous `i` changes value.

Although this document describes a common mistake when dealing with goroutines and closures, it should shed a bit more light on the issue and potential solutions.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes

Comment: Thank you so much for writing this and the helpful link. I now understand about the binding of the variable vs its value (something I was wrongly assuming) and the fact that a variable can be masked with another variable of the same name in an inner block (I was wrong assuming that the iterative variable was scoped inside the loop block.) Thanks!